# Error installing Python Django using pip on Windows 8

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 and pip to install Django on Windows 8 and encountered an Errno22.
I typed "python -m pip install Django==1.7" and get

```
...
...
File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 508, in unzip_file
fp = open(fn, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'c:\\users\\[username]~1\\appda
ta\\local\\temp\\pip_build_[username]\\django\\django/contrib/admin/locale/l
t/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo'
```

Looks like it's a typical backslash problem of pip on Windows. I tried to modify the code in util.py but with in vain. This is an Administrator command prompt so privilege should not be the cause. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Why are you adding `python -m` in front of it?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary did not see your comment, I added it as an answer. Shall I remove it, if it is more suitable as comment?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Just to avoid version conflict. "pip install Django==1.7" gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You are unnecessarily adding an extra parameter: `python -m pip install Django==1.7`

It should be:

`python pip install Django==1.7`

Comment: It's hardly because of this reason. I only added this to avoid version conflicts. I can of course just type "pip install Django==1.7", but it will give the same result.